# Is there a better way quickly check which JS function is responsible for changing something in a webpage?

Tags: javascript

For example, in a webpage that automatically updates the value of something (say, number of votes for a candidate in a news website) I want to quickly find which function is responsible for changing that value, with the hope of finding out where the data came from.

One option I can try is to check the Network timeline of chrome and find which GET request was responsible for that change. But it is not always the case that the script would need to GET something.

Normally I would highlight the part and use chrome's inspect element option. From there I would try to find in the javascript any function that calls/modifies the element. However, in some cases this task is tedious because 
the code might be in one of the dozen javascript files or it may be hard to read. Is there a better way to do this?

I'm wondering how others are doing this?

Comment: A lot of pages minify their scripts to stop people inspecting them and stealing code, in that case you'd just have to trawl through it and figure out what each script is doing.

Comment: you wanna hack a website?